# Props Match Params Id can't be read and Props.id is Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud

If I am using  **const currentUserId = props.id** then the error will be **props.match is undefined**, and the variable "userId" even is undefined when i am trying to console log.
[image]

Then, I using **props.match.params.id** the code can't even being read, it's only blank
[image]

Im also trying to modify the code become **const currentUserId = props.computedMatch.params.id;** but nothing works
[image]

My code:

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import {
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
  Button
} from 'reactstrap';

export const EditUser = (props) => {
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({
    id: '',
    name: ''
  });
  const { users, editUser } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const history = useNavigate();
  const currentUserId = props.match.params.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = currentUserId;
    console.log(typeof userId);
    const selectedUser = users.find(user => user.id === Number(userId))
    setSelectedUser(selectedUser)
    console.log(selectedUser);
  }, [currentUserId, users])

  const onSubmit = () => {
  
    history('/');
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {

  }
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label>Nama</Label>
        <Input type='text' onChange={onChange} placeholder='Ganti Nama Disini!'></Input>
      </FormGroup>
      <Button type='submit'>Edit Data</Button>
      <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger ml-2" style={{ marginLeft: "10px"}}>Cancel</Link>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where is your Router?

Comment: I just follow the tutorial like this

Comment: There must be someplace where you would have defined a Router component, without that how are you redirecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this will fix

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
const { id: currentUserId } = useParams();
```

Answer (score 1):

use withRouter

```js
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'; // here added
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import {
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
  Button
} from 'reactstrap';

const EditUser = (props) => {  // here changed
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({
    id: '',
    name: ''
  });
  const { users, editUser } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const history = useNavigate();
  const currentUserId = this.props.match.params.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = currentUserId;
    console.log(typeof userId);
    const selectedUser = users.find(user => user.id === Number(userId))
    setSelectedUser(selectedUser)
    console.log(selectedUser);
  }, [currentUserId, users])

  const onSubmit = () => {
  
    history('/');
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {

  }
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label>Nama</Label>
        <Input type='text' onChange={onChange} placeholder='Ganti Nama Disini!'></Input>
      </FormGroup>
      <Button type='submit'>Edit Data</Button>
      <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger ml-2" style={{ marginLeft: "10px"}}>Cancel</Link>
    </Form>
  )
}

export default withRouter(EditUser); // here added
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of this.props.match.params.id, you should useParams? It's helps me.
import { useParams} from "react-router-dom";

const { id } = useParams();