# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Tags: reactjs

I tried console.log(this.state.bike). It gave me an array that basically contains everything I need. But when I try to access them I get undefined. How do I access the bikeLocation and bikeDescription? I have added 3 files. BikeServices, ListBikes and ViewBike Components.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BikeServices from '../services/BikeServices';



class viewBike extends Component {
    constructor(props){


        super(props)

        this.state = {
            bikeId: this.props.match.params.bikeId,
            bike: {}
            
        }
        
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        BikeServices.getBikesById(this.state.bikeId).then( (res) => {
            this.setState({bike: res.data});
            //console.log(this.state.bike);
            console.log(this.state.bike.bikeLocation);
        });
    }
       
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                
               <br></br>
                    {this.state.bikeId}
                    
                    <br></br>
                    {this.state.bike.bikeLocation}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default viewBike;



//BikeServices

import axios from 'axios';



const BIKE_URL = `http://localhost:8090/api/v1/bikes`;

class BikeService{


    getBikes(){
        return axios.get(BIKE_URL);
    }

    getBikesById(bikeId){
     
        return axios.get(BIKE_URL+ '/' +bikeId);
        
    }



}

export default new BikeService();


//ListBikes component

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BikeService from '../services/BikeServices'



class ListBikes extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            bikes : [],
        }

        this.viewBike = this.viewBike.bind(this);
    }
    // bikes=[]



    componentDidMount(){
        BikeService.getBikes().then((res) => {
            this.setState({ bikes: res.data});
            
        });
    }

    viewBike(bikeId){
        console.log(this.props)
        this.props.history.push(`/bike/${bikeId}`);
    }
   

    render() {


        return (
           
                <div className='container'>
                    
                
                {
                   
                    this.state.bikes.map(
                        bike=>

                        
                            
                             

                                    <div className="card">
                                        <div className="card-header">
                                        <img src="https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/483/210/436/car-green-4x4-jeep.jpg" alt="rover" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="card-body">
                                        <span className="tag tag-teal">{bike.bikeStatus}</span>
                                        <h4>
                                        Bike Category: {bike.bikeCategory} 
                                        </h4>
                                        <p>
                                        Bike Description: {bike.bikeDescription}
                                        <br></br>
                                        Location: 
                                        {bike.location.address}, {bike.location.city}, {bike.location.state}, {bike.location.zip} 
                                        </p>
                                        
                                        <button style={{marginLeft: "10px"}} onClick={() => this.viewBike(bike.bikeId)} className='btn btn-primary'>View</button>
                                         <button>Rent</button>
                                        

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                

                     
                    )

                }
                
                </div>


                    
            
        );
    }
}

export default ListBikes;
```

I tried console.log(this.state.bike). It gave me an array that basically contains everything I need. But when I try to access them I get undefined. How do I access the bikeLocation and bikeDescription? I have added 3 files. BikeServices, ListBikes and ViewBike Components.

Comment: How do you use `viewBike`?

Comment: React components should start with a big letter; try `ViewBike` instead of `viewBike`

Comment: How does your response look like? If you have more then 1 bike its a high chance it is nested in array so you need to `map()` though it.

Comment: My response,
[{…}]
0
: 
bikeCategory
: 
"Mountain"
bikeDescription
: 
"Black"
bikeId
: 
1000
bikeLocation
: 
"St. Cloud"
bikeStatus
: 
"available"
location
: 
{locationId: 100, state: 'MN', address: '628 8TH Ave E', city: 'St. Cloud', zip: 56301, …}
manufacturer
: 
{manId: 'A100', manName: 'Redline', manCity: 'San Diego'}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
@SinisaM

Comment: I used viewBike to view a bike using ID. I had an API that gives me 5 bikes. I wanted to make a view where I could get one bike using an ID. I was able to fetch the API but couldn't take objects out of it.  @Konrad

Comment: @Dotoku what is the quest now? To show all bikes on a page or show just 1 with all details?

Comment: Show us your `BikeServices` because there is `getBikesById`  function for getting the bikes i guess. `Please edit your question and add it at the bottom not in comment`

Comment: I already have a page that shows all bikes. I want to view just one with all details. @SinisaM I will edit the post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Props Match Params Id can't be read and Props.id is Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952185/props-match-params-id-cant-be-read-and-props-id-is-undefined)

Comment: What do you get then you `console.log(this.state.bike.bikeLocation);` inside `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: I get undefined.